# How to display the contents on a text file which is in tab delimited format as a html table

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I have a text file in which data looks like a table as it is in tab delimited format.

How do i display only few values from the text file in the form of html table.

This is what my text file looks like:

```
@   RUNNO   TRNO R# O# C# CR MODEL... TNAM..................... FNAM.... WSTA.... SOIL_ID...    SDAT    PDAT    EDAT    ADAT    MDAT    HDAT  DWAP    CWAM    HWAM    HWAH    BWAH  PWAM    HWUM  H#AM    H#UM  HIAM  LAIX  IR#M  IRCM  PRCM  ETCM  EPCM  ESCM  ROCM  DRCM  SWXM  NI#M  NICM  NFXM  NUCM  NLCM  NIAM  CNAM  GNAM  PI#M  PICM  PUPC  SPAM  KI#M  KICM  KUPC  SKAM  RECM  ONTAM   ONAM  OPTAM   OPAM   OCTAM    OCAM    DMPPM    DMPEM    DMPTM    DMPIM     YPPM     YPEM     YPTM     YPIM    DPNAM    DPNUM    YPNAM    YPNUM  NDCH TMAXA TMINA SRADA DAYLA   CO2A   PRCP   ETCP   ESCP   EPCP
        1      1  1  0  0 WH CSCER046 DRYLAND  - 0 KG N/HA      KSAS0001 KSAS8101 IBWH980018 1981279 1981289 1981294 1982141 1982174 1982174    46    7615    2848    2848       0  3308  0.0250 11371    22.0 0.374   2.0     0     0   600   422   188   234    12   115   141     1     0   -99    76   127    54    67    54   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99     0   7842   7841      0      0   78645   78603     13.1     18.8     40.5      -99      4.9      7.0     15.1      -99      -99    100.6      -99     37.6   245  13.1   1.2  12.4  12.6  340.7  579.8  405.2    -99    -99
        2      2  1  0  0 WH CSCER046 DRYLAND  - 60 KG N/HA     KSAS0001 KSAS8101 IBWH980018 1981279 1981289 1981294 1982141 1982174 1982174    46   10018    4150    4150       0  4656  0.0288 14411    23.6 0.414   2.5     0     0   600   431   212   219    12   110   139     1    60   -99   105   132    78    94    79   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99     0   7842   7841      0      0   78652   78608     17.3     24.2     47.3      -99      7.2     10.0     19.6      -99    167.0     95.6     69.2     39.6   245  13.1   1.2  12.4  12.6  340.7  579.8  413.4    -99    -99
        3      3  1  0  0 WH CSCER046 DRYLAND  - 180 KG N/HA SP KSAS0001 KSAS8101
```

I just want to display TRNO, Model,  FNAM ,WSTA  in a html table.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: You will need to skip the first record, and then parse each record after that to extract the data you need. Then I would feed the data into a handlebars (or equivalent) template to generate the applicable html. It would be good to try to tackle these various steps and then post your questions with the attempts when you get stuck.

Comment: This seems more like an [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) than a tab separated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data provided seems like a Ascii Table than a tab-seperated values. I have added both solutions.

**A Solution for Ascii Tables - https://jsfiddle.net/libin_v/uutc6gtk/**

1. Use regex to get keys from Header

   ```
   // Get all keys from Header Row
   var lines = asciiTable.split('\n');
   var regexPattern = /\S+\s*/g;
   var headers = lines[0].match(regexPattern);
   ```
2. Fetch individual Values, by splicing the line using the Keys we just parsed. The keys are not yet trimmed (they do have their whitespace along with them). This makes splicing the data possible.

   ```
   // fetch individual values (Also filter based on allowed keys)
   var allowedKeys = ["TRNO", "MODEL...", "FNAM....", "WSTA...."];
   for (i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
     start = 0;
     value = "";
     valueArray = [];
     headers.forEach(function(key) {
       if (allowedKeys.includes(key.trim())) {
         value = lines[i].slice(start, start + key.length);
         valueArray.push(value.trim());
       }
       start += key.length;
     });
     rows.push(valueArray);
   }
   ```
3. Complete the 2D Array by inserting the headers

   ```
   // Insert Header in array
   headers.forEach(function(key) {
     if (allowedKeys.includes(key.trim())) {
       valueArray.push(key.trim());
     }
   });
   rows.unshift(valueArray);
   ```
4. Render 2D array as HTML Table - Thanks to @veganista for the [gist to convert 2D array to HTML](https://gist.github.com/veganista/6413299)

   ```
   // Display 2D-array in Table
   var table = arrayToTable(rows, {
     thead: true,
     attrs: {
       class: 'table'
     }
   })
   ```

**A Solution for Tab Separated Values - https://jsfiddle.net/libin_v/cpa8xy85/**

1. Convert these to objects. I used [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com)

   ```
   // Convert Tab Seperated Values to Objects
   var results = Papa.parse(tabSeperatedString, config);
   console.log("Results:", results);
   ```
2. Transform the object with keys we like. (simply put, Remove the unwanted keys)

   ```
   // Remove unwanted keys
   var allowedKeys = ["TRNO", "MODEL...", "FNAM....", "WSTA...."];
   results.data.forEach(function(row) {
       Object.keys(row).forEach(function(key) {
          if (allowedKeys.includes(key) === false) {
             delete row[key];
          }
       });
   });
   console.log("Stripped results:", results);
   ```
3. Convert these objects to HTML

   ```
   // generate html
   var html = "<table border='1|1'>";
   Object.keys(results.data[0]).forEach(function(key) {
     html += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
   });

   results.data.forEach(function(row) {
     html += "<tr>";
     Object.keys(row).forEach(function(key) {
       html += "<td>" + row[key] + "</td>";
     });
     html += "</tr>";
   });
   html += "</table>";

   $('body').append(html);
   ```